# SQL Server DB Trigger

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I need to insert a row into a table if a particular row in another table is updated.

How do I do an IF statement in the the DB trigger on Table1, saying if Table1.column1 = 'TC' then INSERT a row in Table2.

Answer (score 1):

You would do this in an update trigger on the 'other' table.

There are two special tables in triggers: `inserted` and `deleted`.  You join these two tables in such a way that the result set is the rows you wish to insert.  Ergo -

```
create trigger [after_update_on_Table1] on [Table1] for update
as
    ...
    insert
        into [Table2] (...)
    select
        ...
    from
        inserted as i
            inner join
        deleted as d
            on (i.<*pk*> = d.<*pk*>)
    where
        <*other conditions if applicable*>
    ...
```

<*pk*> is whatever the appropriate primary key would be.  If this is a compound primary key then AND together the different primary key components.

For what you describe thus far you do not require an `if` statement.